# UNIX: Linking an executeable to both a static library and dynamic library?

Tags: unix, compiler-construction, linker, libraries

I admit this is a homework question that asks if this is possible. I believe the answer to it is yes, however I do not know the answer to the question 'why?'. To me, it seems like the answer is simply 'why not?'... can anyone provide some deeper insight to why this is true (or untrue, if I am wrong)? It seems like this question would only be asked if there was a tricky part to it, but from what I understand of compiling, there doesn't seem to be anything that would disallow linking to both.

Comment: How would you do it? Did you try it? Did it work? ;-) Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course you can link both a static library and a dynamic library. Linking to a static library is essentially the same as grabbing the required object files from the archive and including them in the linking process.

If the static library and the dynamic library you're linking is for the *same* library, then the dynamic link is redundant. It's still allowed to be done, but it'd be pointless (and just introduces an unnecessary runtime dependency for your executable, at least on Unix).

Comment: On some *nixes with a single linker symbolspace like FreeBSD and Linux, it might actually be impossible to link the same lib static and shared.

Answer (score 1):

In general, there should be no reason why you can't link to both static and dynamic libraries, especially if they do not conflict (for instance, provide the same symbols).  The mechanism to do so will differ depending on your complier, but many Free Software projects actually do this -- they build a so-called "convenience library" statically that then gets linked into a dynamically linked executable.

Comment: I guess that is why I am having trouble answering the question 'why?'. It seems like it's just because there is no reason you can't.

Comment: @Logan The best answer I can come up with is that there is practically no difference from the linker's point of view between a series of objects on the linker command line (a.o b.o c.o) and a static library that contains them (libfoo.a).  In the first case, it should be obvious that you can also link against a shared library, so, as the second case is nearly equivalent, you can link that against a shared library as well.